# Changing SpeechRecognizer language on Azure Cognitive Services

Tags: python, azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use azure's cognitive service Speech to Text following the Github example in `Python`: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/258949599ec32c8a7b03fb38a53f2033010b6b26/samples/python/console/speech_sample.py#L203

I couldn't find in documentation how to change the speaker language recognition, default is English and I want to transcript an audio in spanish.

I think it's with `SpeechRecognizer` function, but I don't get how to use it properly.

This is the code example of Github that I'm using:

```py
def speech_recognize_continuous_from_file():
    """performs continuous speech recognition with input from an audio file"""
    # <SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=weatherfilename)

    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    speech_recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    # stop continuous recognition on either session stopped or canceled events
    speech_recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)

    # Start continuous speech recognition
    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()
    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)
    # </SpeechContinuousRecognitionWithFile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpeechConfig` constructor takes a `speech_recognition_language` argument.  You must specify the language in BCP-47 format.

```
language = 'es-ES' # or perhaps es-MX?

speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=speech_key,
                                       region=service_region,
                                       speech_recognition_language=language)
```

Additional documentation for the class is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-cognitiveservices-speech/azure.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig?view=azure-python).

Comment: Is it possible to set the `speech_recognition_language` on runtime when the instance is already created?